# Command disabled Fusing up lines of code, maths mode

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, lyx, grouping, lyx-layouts

I appear to often accidentally hit the wrong keys when type code within sentences with ordinary lines of text. I accidentally do this too much, it will fuse the entire line together making it almost impossible to edit or cut out individual parts of it it converse the entire line into mathss code and moreover scroll out over the margins.

[image: screenshot of a fused up piece of math-code highlighted which also over runs the margins, it appears to do so without asking for my permission explicitely]

I believes it must be some kind of maths mode command. As a lot of previous commands no longer works, including certain symbol notation and the inclusion of maths code. It also changes sub-sections into propositions and re-orders spacing, fonts, and will not get rid of solutions/proposito/definition command/corrollariess as usual, by clicking on the scroll down and clicking on standard

Comment: In my opinion, LyX is just not an efficient way to prepare documents.

Answer (score 1):

(1)What causes this behavior? as in the picture below and my written description.

`Lyx` appears to have suddenly changed the format of my document. It says `local layout` has been changed but I cannot find out what it was originally nor when it was altered, nor what it is, and how to revert the document back to its original `local layout.`

(A) My written text, particularly if it includes `math code`, has been altered and changed as the text/math code= becomes stretched outside the margins.

(B) `propositions,definitions, theorem` `headings` and cannot be removed and have been  are added everywhere - where these used to be `sub-sub-sections` headings, for instance.

, `enumeration` is added everywhere the entire font changes or particular if one does this within `math mode?`[![stretched out code outside of margins][1]][1]

(2[![enter image description here][2]][2])  Does adding number lists within `propositions`,  `solutions` and `math,mode` have the potential to change the layout or mess up the document?

[![stretches out math code, and line spacing excessive enumeration][3]][3]

(2)I note that adding too much `math code` , within separate `math boxes` on the same line alongside `standard text` has quite often caused problems.

**Does `Lyx`** sometimes presume, that the entire line should or should not be put into a `single math box,` and thus enacts  or tries to correct it, the issue, without warning. Or presume that there is some kind of format that you want and automatically change that document as well as related documents to that layout without ones permission.

Particularly if there are too many errors that it cannot handle.

Incidentally where do you find the error reports within `lyx`, for any given specific `Lyx` document?

Thus, sometimes,  fusing lines together, and causes code to overflow the margins, and changing the `local layout` ?. Or changing things that were intendeds to be changed such as the `local layout`?

(3)Moreover,cutting,out chunks,of,`code,`that over,flows,theds,or,text, as one notices when there is a comma between every word and thus it was once in maths-code, which it sometimes cuts out without ones permission, One notices this due to instance oif `hello,this,is,a,symbol,for` behavior, sometimes its in a distinct black font otherwise it is not`\,[![enter image description here][4]][4]

(4) I also get error messages related to `local layout being chang`ed, or not `command disabled` which never used to be. Can something cause Lyx to automatically change the `formatting` and font, layout and entire local layout` of the document without my permissions.

```
(5)Including cutting out chunks of important code, if it overlows the margins?
```

For example, if after lyx suddenly crashes, one had notto save the document. When onen retries or tries use a temporary file or backup file,  sometimes without warning or just closes without even an error message,

or uses /`two tabs` of the `same lyx document open simultaneously` OR if one accidentally `copies`math code over the top and accidentally pastes it over the top of entire sections, can this trigger this behavior?

In particular what causes `Lyx` to become excessively slow? 
Such as :
Lots of spelling errors
layour errors/format errors
-copies of the same document or too many picture/notes/footnotes, 
-very large chunks of text, inter-dispersed with `math code`
- ,math- code errors,-
- spelling errors,-[![spelling errors and large chunks of text, with different format, the rest is spaced out, with spell checker things crawl to a halt][5]][5]
 large chunks of text.
-too many tabs or different version of lyx open
- having the same file open twice, or a temporary version of the same file open simultaneously.

Is there any way of finding out the errors that `Lyx` detects. I notice that when I have test like this. interspersed with math code, it Lyx crawls to a halt[ continually finding older versions of documents within a newer version or with spelling errors or newer content being cut out without permission
enter image description here

(6) will lyx sometimes merge multiple versions of the same document into one, including older version if it

(A) crashes

(B) When one copies large sections `math's-code` of an older version of the same `Lyx document` into the same or a similar document; particular if that is pasted into the middle of `maths-code box`

```
[![maths code ending up as section names][5]][5]
```

(D) Accidentally copies a large section of text or copies of `math-code` and puts into a distinct layout, will it change the `local layout`automatically
(E) has two much  `math's-code` within a standard paragraph that are in distinct `maths code boxes`.
(F) has too many versions of similar content , particularly `maths code` or `math boxes` or **multi line equation**s, **grids** , `interspersed between text` and other pieces of code that are not in said grid. 
-Or if  one has too many pictures will this causes lyx `to crawl, crash or merge content together`, creating a mess?

I note that it will often cut out sections of code and throw them all over the place as if `Lyx`  sometimes decides or predicts what it is one wishes to do.

(7)If there is a way to detect error messages or if find where they are mentioned, That would be useful. I also note that the bug report/error log/details command is disabled , when a warning appears,

often-times when an error message appears

(7) sometimes , Lyx will instantly cut out entire swaths of code if one hits the wrong key or move you down to an entire section
[![turns paragraph into an entire section name[![][5]][9]][9]][10][![enter image description here][11]][11]